# How to get old elide behaviour in QTableWidget with Qt 5.12?

Tags: qt5, qtablewidget

I recently upgraded my Linux and the Qt version changed from 5.9.5 to 5.12.8. Now the elide behaviour in all QTableWidgets has changed and immediately removes long words from the end when shrinking a column.

[image: wide enough column]

After shrinking the column a bit:

[image: too small column]

I already set the `textElideMode` for that QTableWidget to `ElideNone`, but it has no affect:

[image: text elide mode]

**How can I restore the old behaviour, where only parts of the last word disappear?**